# Tampermonkey script keeps clicking on button

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I am completely new to Javascript/Tampermonkey. I am trying to make a Tampermonkey script that (fast) clicks once on a specific page button as soon as the page loads. After the mouse click, the website asks for a verification. The verification has to be done manually.

This is the code of the button on the website:

```
<button class="btn  btn--arrow  push-right  js-continue-scrollposition" type="submit" id="btnSave" name="Command" value="plaats">Send</button>
```

This is my script in Tampermonkey:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Test
// @namespace    Test
// @version      1
// @description  test
// @author       Me
// @match        LINK OF THE WEBSITE HERE
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
(function() {
document.querySelector("#btnSave").click();

})();
```

This code seems to work fine but there is only one problem. The script keeps spamming the button on the website. I only want to generate one (fast!) mouse click on the button, and after that the script needs to be stopped or paused so I can do the verification. I've been busy for a whole day but I can't find a solution. Maybe someone can help?

Please keep in mind that I am completely new to this. This is my first day of using all of this.

Comment: What happens when the button is clicked ? Maybe it reloads the page and then the script run again since the page is reloaded (this might make an infinite loop)

Comment: Afther the click, it opens the reCaptcha verification within the same page and the button ‘btnSave’ is still visible.  What can I do to prevent the script from looping?

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this.

Make a boolean named "isClicked" and set it to false, then when you run the code, check if the script has clicked the button, if yes change the boolean to true. Then stop the function.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Test
// @namespace    Test
// @version      1
// @description  test
// @require      https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js
// @author       Me
// @match        LINK OF THE WEBSITE HERE
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

var $ = window.$;                //  Avoids warnings in TamperMonkey
var isClicked = false;

window.setInterval(function(){
   if(!isClicked){               //  !isClicked checks if the boolean is not true
      $("#btnSave").click();
   }
}, 1000);                        //  1000 stands for the refresh rate of this function in milliseconds

$("#btnSave").click(function(){  //  Functions when button is clicked
   isClicked = true;
});
```

This answer uses [jQuery (JavaScript Library)](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp) for simplified javascript.

**Note:** You have to import the jQuery Library in the Meta/Header "UserScript" by the following:

`// @require      https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js`